# Visual Studio 2015 - Debug ASP.NET MVC source code immediately on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I'm having a problem with the default model binder being slow in my ASP.NET MVC web application on a specific controller.  I'm looking to basically debug immediately when I hit the `POST` and see the ASP.NET MVC source code that is fired first (the model binder, etc.) before my controller's code.

How can I do this? I thought this should be an easy task but Google isn't turning anything up. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Can you share us a screen shot about the source code debugging in your side? Do you enable the option "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" under Tools->Options->Debugging? Please  disable it and check “Enable Just My Code” option. Debug it again.

Comment: What about this issue? This document shared us the steps how to steo into MVC souce code, if you want to debug it or not, you could enable/disable some debugging options: https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I think the latter option will work if I hit an early breakpoint.  Thanks!

Comment: So it has been resolved, am I right? If so, I will add the comment as an answer.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Yes, go ahead.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your friendly response, I add the solution, if it is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug ASP.NET MVC source code, it was related some debugging options under TOOLS->Options->Debugging.
[image]

It also was related to the Microsoft Symbols Server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

So if you want to debug MVC source code or not, please enable/disable them, view the results.

Reference:

https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/stepping-into-asp-net-mvc-source-code-with-visual-studio-debugger